# File Storage in Photos on elementary OS

Tags: photos

Does Photos on elementary OS store photos in regular file structure or one giant file like iPhoto? I want to make sure I can declare a folder within Dropbox so my photos are always synced up and backed up.

Secondary, is there a good one click import tool to bring my photos over from iphoto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not have a database file that it puts them in. If you import a picture it will create dated folders [2016-10-10] or you can drag the photo in to the pictures folder directly and it will load

Comment: Okay perfect so it sounds like it will integrate nicely with dropbox. Thanks! Have you heard of any great iphoto importer?